# Why does my javascript slow down in Safari but not Chrome?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, safari

is there something I can put in my javascript or html to make Safari clear out any buffers that might be slowing it down? Chrome seems to work much better on my website. It seems calling google charts many times on Safari gets slow, but not on Chrome. My website is here: https://sdeban.github.io/Muscle-models/MuscleExplorer.html

If there were some code I could put in the html to cause/ask the browser to flush it's memory, that would be great. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems calling google charts many times on Safari gets slow, but not on Chrome

Google Charts is going to obviously be better optimized on Chrome.

Also, javascript is what's causing the page to load slower. Usually to make pages run faster javascript is *disabled*, so pages that require heavy javascript (like yours) will naturally be slower to load.

As far as your question, I'm not sure if there's a lot you can do besides maybe editing your website to be "lighter" with less javascripting.

Comment: Thanks. I figured is was loading Charts so many times, but I was hoping there was something I could do to make Safari flush its cache. Oddly, it works fine on Safari mobile.

Comment: Cache clearing is usually only available on the client side. So you can clear your own Safari cache, but you cannot make your site clear someone else's cache. Also, if my answer helped, please upvote to increase visibility.